# Nodejs Sharp Image Resize and Upload to S3 gives timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sharp

Below code is not working for me, it's giving timeout issue with while uploading the images to Amazon S3.

```
function resizeAndUploadToS3( imageData, imageHeader, bucket, key ) {
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    sharp( imageData.data ).resize( 100, 100 ).toBuffer( function ( err, data ) {
      s3.putObject( {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: imageHeader['content-type'],
        ContentLength: imageHeader['content-length'],
        Body: data
      }, ( err, status ) => {
        console.log( 'err:::', err );
        console.log( 'status:::', status );
        resolve( status );
      } );
    } );
  } );
}
```

I tried to save resized image into the **local** file using below code and its working fine

```
sharp( imageData.data ).resize( 100, 100 ).toFile('test.jpg');
```

Also, I tried to upload the images **without** resizing to S3 and it works fine. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing given lines from above code.

```
ContentType: imageHeader['content-type'],
ContentLength: imageHeader['content-length'],
```

I think value of **content-type** and **content-length** was wrong in my case.

Comment: I think that only `content-length` was the culprit, in my case I removed it and it worked.